# How do I pass a function AND a variable list of arguments to another function in C?

Tags: c, function, pointers, syntax

I want to pass an arbitrary function and it's arguments to another function in C.

For example like the code below (which obviously does not work)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void doit(int (*f)(...), char *fname, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, fname);
    f(argptr)
    va_end(argptr);
}   

int func1(char *a, int b)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "func1 %s %d\n", a, b);
}   

int func2(char *a, int b, int c)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "func2 %s %d %d\n", a, b, c);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    doit(func1, "func1", "blah", 10);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work

Comment: I understand how basic function pointers work.  My question is to see if you can pass in variable arguments to a function.  This in theory is possible because at the end of the day, the arguments are just passed on the stack.  I can do this in assembler easily, wondering if there is a C trick to do it without resorting to assembly

Comment: The C standard does not mandate a stack. And typical ABIs don't use only the stack to pass arguments.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need va_list forwarders to your functions if you want to have them participate in such a scheme. Something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void doit(int (*f)(va_list va), char *fname, ...)
{
    va_list argptr;
    va_start(argptr, fname);
    f(argptr);
    va_end(argptr);
}

int func1(const char *a, int b)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "func1 %s %d\n", a, b);
    return 0;
}

int func1_va(va_list va)
{
    const char * a = va_arg(va, const char*);
    int b = va_arg(va, int);
    return func1(a,b);
}

int func2(const char *a, int b, int c)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "func2 %s %d %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}

int func2_va(va_list va)
{
    const char *a = va_arg(va, const char*);
    int b = va_arg(va, int);
    int c = va_arg(va, int);
    return func2(a,b,c);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    doit(func1_va, "func1", "blah", 10);
    doit(func2_va, "func2", "blahblah", 100, 200);

    return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
func1 blah 10
func2 blahblah 100 200
```

Comment: Thank you!  Exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @WhozCraig the first elements of the variadic arguments (`"func1"` and `"func2"`) get dropped, is that intentionally?

Comment: @deamentiaemundi they're not dropped, and they're not part of the va_list. They're a formal paramter to the `fname` argument of `doit`, and are simply not used (the OP chose to do that, i was just following suit). Do they even need to be there? Not really. We could just-as-easily based `va_start` from `f`.

Comment: @WhozCraig, Can't the wrapper functions func1_va and func2_va be made generic?  Perhaps if they took in a char *fmt (like printf does) and parse the format and pass in  the arguments to the function they are invoking?

Comment: That's why I asked (I never drop the first element, I don't want it wasted. But I have been raised in harsher times, when memory was not only sparse but horribly expensive, too )

Comment: @stevelandiss Far more  difficult, and more platform-specific, than I think you may first realize.

Answer (score 0):

First: don't mess with **va_args** if you have no idea how arguments are passed or how activation records work.

Your best bet is to declare doit() with excessively many args:

**void  doit( void ( *p_func )(), int arg1, int arg2, int arg3, int arg4, int arg5 );**

and just call ( *p_func )() with all those arguments.  If the function being called doesn't reach for more than it needs, there won't be any trouble.  Even if it does, it will just pull garbage values off the stack.

Comment: This is [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) specific. On x86-64 it probably would work, but there is no guarantee for other architectures.